# Visual Studio 2013 C++ memory and performance profiler plugins

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to move my code into Visual Studio 2013 for some reasons,
Since I'm using C++ and C# and can buy only 1 profiler. I chose ANTS C# profiler,but I need a profiler for C++.

Until Visual Studio 2012 I had no problem using the performance and memory built in into VS for C++.

I understand that VS2013 doesn't have a built-in profiler.

I have looked into some tools, I would rather use a free plugin. 
Can you recommend one or explain from you experience the pros and cons of each tool you know of?

I have heard about these 3:
 1. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c40a5d8-dd35-4019-a2af-cb1403f5939c

2. Intel Parallel Studio (vtune)
3. dotmemory

Comment: why did you vote close? this is a valid question. there isn't such a question on SOF, and will save tons of people time and effort?

Comment: this is off-topic by the (have to say: stupid) rules of the site - it's about a recommendation. it will probably get closed. what a shame.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I really hate this stupid rule, how can one of the most used IDE's for programmers features are off topic ???

Comment: i'll do the research on my own. this is just... nevermind, close it down if you want

Comment: I'm just explaining. To summarize it: It's just LIFE. Carry on ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath lol! my kind of man! thanks

Comment: There is a performance profiler in VS2013 (Ultimate anyway) with CPU profiling and instrumentation options. I've used Intel Parallel Studio but mainly been interested in its race condition detection not memory profiling. The race condition detection is good, provided it understands the threading libraries (it has trouble with Boost ASIO for example).

Comment: @softwariness cool thanks, have you tried openMP, or TBB? although i guess Intel Parallel Studio will support other Intel's supported products...

Comment: From recollection they are both supported (though I haven't used them myself), as are the standard Windows threading APIs.